# Query in the proof of Wick's theorem

Tags: operators, commutator, wick-theorem

I am looking at the proof of Wick's theorem in the notes here:

https://www.imperial.ac.uk/media/imperial-college/research-centres-and-groups/theoretical-physics/msc/current/qft/handouts/qftwickstheorem.pdf

I have difficulty trying to understand on page 7 how we can rewrite eqn 36 as eqn 39.

Equation 36 says:
$$
X_{C} = [\phi_{1}^{+},N(\phi_{2}....\phi_{m})].\tag{36}
$$

Equation 39 says:
$$
X_{C} = N([\phi_{1}^{+},\phi_{2}....\phi_{m}]) = \sum_{i=2}^{m}N(\phi_{2}...\phi_{i-1}[\phi_{1}^{+},\phi_{i}]\phi_{i+1}...\phi_{m}).\tag{39}
$$

I understand the expansion in the final term. What i could not understand is how the commutator can be brought inside the normal product i.e.

$$
[\phi_{1}^{+},N(\phi_{2}....\phi_{m})] = N([\phi_{1}^{+},\phi_{2}....\phi_{m}])
$$

I tried checking if this is true for a simple case for $m = 3$. After a long calculation i got:

$$
[\phi_{1}^{+},N(\phi_{2}\phi_{3})] = \phi_{1}^{+}\phi_{2}^{-}\phi_{3}^{-} - \phi_{2}^{-}\phi_{3}^{-}\phi_{1}^{+} + \phi_{1}^{+}\phi_{2}^{-}\phi_{3}^{+} - \phi_{2}^{-}\phi_{3}^{+}\phi_{1}^{+} + \phi_{1}^{+}\phi_{3}^{-}\phi_{2}^{+} - \phi_{3}^{-}\phi_{2}^{+}\phi_{1}^{+} 
$$
and,

$$
N([\phi_{1}^{+},\phi_{2}\phi_{3}]) = 2*\phi_{3}^{-}\phi_{1}^{+}\phi_{2}^{+} + 2*\phi_{2}^{-}\phi_{1}^{+}\phi_{3}^{+}   
$$

So it seems that the equation is not true unless i made a calculation mistake.
Can someone please explain?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.